# retrieve data from external json file

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, jsx

i have a json file with some data in it and a jsx file with a button and a div so i want to retrieve the json data when i click the button inside my jsx file into the div i have and i don't have a clue how to do it .

my json file name is data.json i want to get the data in that json file when i click (infoBtn) into (dataDisplay)Div also the data in my json file is:

```
{
"countries": ["Iraq", "Turkey", "Yemen"],
  "bootcamps": [
    "Web Development Bootcamp",
    "Android Development Bootcamp",
    "UI/UX Design Bootcamp"
  ],
  "camps": {
    "iraq": [
      "Android Bootcamp, Erbil 2017",
      "Android Bootcamp, Erbil 2018",
      "Web Development Bootcamp, Erbil 2018",
      "Web Development Bootcamp, Qaraqosh 2018",
      "Advanced Android Bootcamp, Erbil 2019",
      "Web Development Bootcamp, Erbil 2020",
      "Web Development Bootcamp, Mosul 2020",
      "UI/UX Design Bootcamp Erbil 2020"
    ],
    "turkey": [
      "Android Bootcamp, Sanliurfa 2017",
      "Android Bootcamp, Istanbul 2018",
      "Web Development Bootcamp, Gaziantep 2019",
      "Web Development Bootcamp, Istanbul Dec 2019",
      "Web Development Bootcamp, Istanbul Feb 2020",
      "Web Development Bootcamp, Istanbul Jun 2020"
    ],
    "yemen": [
      "Web Development Bootcamp, Sana'a 2018",
      "Web Development Bootcamp, Sana'a 2019",
      "Web Development Bootcamp, Sana'a 2020"
    ]
  }
}
```

like this ex:

```
import React from 'react';

    const Main = () => {    
  
       return (
     
          <div class="buttons">
        
            <div class="infoDiv"> 
         
               <button id="infoBtn">More Info</button>

            </div>

          <div id="dataDisplay"></div>
                   
      );
    };

       export default Main;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it external and sometimes changing? Then you need to use [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) with `JSON.parse()` to retrieve it from your server. Otherwise, you want to put `import * as jsonData from "./the_file.json"` at the top of your JSX file and use `jsonData` as an object.

Comment: if that's not enough and you also wanna know how to make the button display the data, you should have put a different title

Comment: its local file not in any server

Comment: local in the source code or on the user's pc?

Comment: in the user pc.

Comment: you can't fetch a file on the user's pc seamlessly, only with a file selection window

Comment: can you please tell me how to do that ?

Comment: you want to have the file on your server, i think. use the first solution

Comment: is it the only way ? send it to my server then use fetch?

Comment: if you're not going to update the file very often, use the second solution; it hard-codes the json

Answer (score -1):

```
import React from 'react';

const Main = () => {    

    function handleClick(evt){
        var elem = document.getElementById("TARGET_DIV_ID_HERE");
        fetch('URL_TO_JSON_HERE')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                elem.innerHTML = data;
                console.log('Success:', data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                elem.innerHTML = "fetch error";
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });

    }

    return (
    
        <div class="buttons">
    
        <div class="infoDiv"> 
        
            <button id="infoBtn" onClick={handleClick} >More Info</button>

        </div>

        <div id="dataDisplay"></div>
                
    );
};

export default Main;
```

Comment: you didn't even describe how and why it works

Comment: also `document.getElementById` and `elem.innerHTML = ` isn't how you use react

Comment: sorry for late answer i was at work .. i already used your code up there and it change the div to fetch error

Comment: Are you targeting the correct file in URL_TO_JSON_HERE ?